# MVC RegisterRoutes MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ); 

         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Process",
             url: "Process/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Process", action = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

1.  Could you please help me in understanding why **I get HTTP 404 error** when I hit http://localhost:7841/Process
However, I am able to see my page when I hit 
http://localhost:7841/Process/list

2. Also, if i hardcode controller( **url: "Home/{action}/{id}"**) in both the routes URLs(see below) why I get “**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**” error.

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Home",
           url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       ); 

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Process",
            url: "Process/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Process", action = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```

Kindly help me in understanding Routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you request `yourBaseUrl/Process/`, It matches the route pattern `{controller}/{action}/{id}` which is the url pattern for your **first** route defined(the one called `Home`). So it will try to send the request to the action method and since you do not have the action method segment in the request url, it will try to use the default one defined in that route registration, which is `Index`. You are getting a 404 because you do not have an `Index` action method inside your `ProcessController`. If you add an `Index()` action method to your `ProcessController`, It will execute that and return the result from that.

Ideally, you should define all your specific route definition before the generic route definition. If you want `/Process` to return the response returned by the `List` method, set that as the default action in the route registration.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Process",
    url: "Process/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Process", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Another option is to use the default generic route registration as it is in the `RouteConfig` and use [attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) to make `List` method to be handled by `/Process/` request.

```
public class ProcessController : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.Route("Process")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return Content("process list action method :)");
    }
}
```